# Integration Of Functions With Multiple Variables And Constants in R

Tags: r

I will try to integrate a simple function using R.
If I want to integrate, let say this:
f(x) = a*x.

How can I say integrate this without defining a?
I tried the following:

> f <- function(x, a) {a*x}
>
> integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = 2)

It doesn't seem to work.

Additional questions:

- How can I integrate functions without defining the "boundary".
  So, the desired output will be a/2*x^2 + c
- How can I integrate in the the multidimensionel space?

Any help is appreciated. I hope you will give me some examples.

Comment: So when you say you want to integrate `f(x) = a*x.` without defining `a`, what exactly is the desired output? A function? Are you trying to do symbolic algebra?

Comment: My desired output is a function. So in the following example, I would like the output to be a/2 *x^2

Comment: Have you tried [Ryacas](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-as-a-computer-algebra-system-with-ryacas/)? Note that I have never worked with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any arguments of the function `f` in the `...` argument of `integrate`. Below, I did this by passing `a = 3` to the function. This can be extended to an arbitrary number of arguments.

```
> f <- function(x, a) {
      a * x
  }
> result <- integrate(f, lower = 0, upper = 2, a = 3)
> result$value
[1] 6
```

Comment: Setting `a = 3` doesn't seem to answer OP's question of how to "*integrate this without defining `a`*"...

Comment: Yes. Like Gregor said. I would like to integrate this function for an arbitrary a.